# nmap shows excessive number of open ports

Tags: kali-linux, nmap

I was just running an nmap scan of a website, which turns out it has an excessive number of open ports. I honestly have never seen anything like it. Of all 65,000+ ports, almost all of them are open, including port 8333 running a Bitcoin service.

Now, when I ran an -sV scan, almost all of these open ports are tcpwrapped. So my two questions are:

1. What does tcpwrapped mean, and does it make the server more or less vulnerable?
2. What the heck is port 8333 running a Bitcoin server?

Partial scan result:

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE      VERSION
1/tcp     open     tcpwrapped
3/tcp     open     tcpwrapped
4/tcp     open     tcpwrapped
6/tcp     open     tcpwrapped
7/tcp     open     tcpwrapped
9/tcp     open     tcpwrapped
13/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
17/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
19/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
20/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
21/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
22/tcp    open     ssh?
23/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
24/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
25/tcp    filtered smtp
26/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
30/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
32/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
33/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
37/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
42/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
43/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
49/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
53/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
70/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
79/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
80/tcp    open     http         Apache httpd
81/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
82/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
83/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
84/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
85/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
88/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
89/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
90/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
99/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
100/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
106/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
109/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
110/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
111/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
113/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
119/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
125/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
135/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
143/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
144/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
146/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
161/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
163/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
179/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
199/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
211/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
212/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
222/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
254/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
255/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
256/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
259/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
264/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
280/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
301/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
306/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
311/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
340/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
366/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
389/tcp   filtered ldap
406/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
407/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
416/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
417/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
425/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
427/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
443/tcp   open     ssl/http     Apache httpd
444/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
458/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
464/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
465/tcp   closed   smtps
481/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
497/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
500/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
512/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
513/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
514/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
515/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
524/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
541/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
543/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
544/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
545/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
548/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
554/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
555/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
563/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
587/tcp   closed   submission
593/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
616/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
617/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
625/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
631/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
636/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
646/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
648/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
666/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
667/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
668/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
683/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
687/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
691/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
700/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
705/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
711/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
714/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
720/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
722/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
726/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
749/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
765/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
777/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
783/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
787/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
800/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
801/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
808/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
843/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
873/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
880/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
888/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
898/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
900/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
901/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
902/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
903/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
911/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
912/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
981/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
987/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
990/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
992/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
993/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
995/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
999/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
1000/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1001/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1002/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1007/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1009/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1010/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1011/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1021/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1022/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1023/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1024/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1025/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1026/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1027/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1028/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1029/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1030/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1031/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1032/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1033/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1034/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1035/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1036/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1037/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1038/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1039/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1040/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1041/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1042/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1043/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1044/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1045/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1046/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1047/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1048/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1049/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1050/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1051/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1052/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1053/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1054/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1055/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1056/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1057/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1058/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1059/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1060/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1061/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1062/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1063/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1064/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1065/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1066/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1067/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1068/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1069/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1070/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1071/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1072/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1073/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1074/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1075/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1076/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1077/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1078/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1079/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1080/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1081/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1082/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1083/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1084/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1085/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1086/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1087/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1088/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1089/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1090/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1091/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1092/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1093/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1094/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1095/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1096/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1097/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1098/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1099/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1100/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1102/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1104/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1105/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1106/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1107/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1108/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1110/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1111/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1112/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1113/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1114/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1117/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1119/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1121/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1122/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1123/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1124/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1126/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1130/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1131/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1132/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1137/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1138/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1141/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1145/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1147/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1148/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1149/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1151/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1152/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1154/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1163/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1164/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1165/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1166/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1169/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1174/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1175/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1183/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1185/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1186/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1187/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1192/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1198/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1199/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1201/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1213/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1216/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1217/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1218/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1233/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1234/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1236/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1244/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1247/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1248/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1259/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1271/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1272/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1277/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1287/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1296/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1300/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1301/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1309/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1310/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1311/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1322/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1328/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1334/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1352/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1417/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1433/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1434/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1443/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1455/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1461/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1494/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1500/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1501/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1503/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1521/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1524/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1533/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1556/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1580/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1583/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1594/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1600/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1641/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1658/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1666/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1687/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1688/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1700/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1717/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1718/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1719/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1720/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1721/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1723/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1755/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1761/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1782/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1783/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1801/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1805/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1812/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1839/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1840/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1862/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1863/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1864/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1875/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1900/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1914/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1935/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1947/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1971/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1972/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1974/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1984/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1998/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
1999/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2000/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2001/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2002/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2003/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2004/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2005/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2006/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2007/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2008/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2009/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2010/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2013/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2020/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2021/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2022/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2030/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2033/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2034/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2035/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2038/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2040/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2041/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2042/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2043/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2045/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
2046/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
```

Comment: [TCP Wrapper](https://superuser.com/questions/84421/what-does-it-mean-when-a-portscan-shows-a-port-as-tcpwrapped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of all 65,000+ ports, almost all of them are open

The server is configured to return fake TCP SYN-ACK responses to all connection attempts. This could be either part of intrusion prevention (it's a known technique for preventing port scans), or part of DDoS prevention (badly configured [SYNPROXY](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Synproxy) filter that's supposed to protect against SYN floods).

> including port 8333 running a Bitcoin service.

It's not necessarily running a Bitcoin service. It's a port that nmap's "known ports list" has *labelled* as belonging to Bitcoin. Is it actually running bitcoind? Probably not. It could be running something else on that port. Or it could just be showing up for the same reason *all other ports* are showing up in the scan.

Though it *could* actually be running bitcoind. It depends on what website you scanned. Some people run their personal websites all from a single multi-purpose server that also runs their mail system, their databases, their Minecraft server, etc. It would be surprising to see non-web services if you scanned a professional web hosting provider's system – but it's not surprising at all if you scanned someone's self-managed VPS.

> What does tcpwrapped mean, and does it make the server more or less vulnerable?

It means the server accepted the TCP connection, but then immediately closed.

This is similar to the behavior of the "tcp_wrappers" library that some services use for IP-based access control (you might also know it as `/etc/hosts.deny`) – because it works at service level it comes in too late to outright reject connections, so if the host is not allowed it'll just close the connection as soon as it's accepted. Hence the "tcpwrapped" label that nmap assigns.

Use `--reason` to have nmap tell you why it came to its conclusion regarding each port.

It doesn't actually mean the server uses tcp_wrappers though – nmap only sees the *behavior* but not the actual software. If applied to single ports like 22 (ssh), it would be tcp_wrappers. If applied to all possible ports, it's more likely to be SYNPROXY or something similar.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it is a company website. Now, I did run the --reason option, and it returned syn-ack ttl 64 for almost all of the open ports. What I don't understand is why would they leave the ports open when they could just close them. Sure it's firewalled, but... 
On a different note, the site is outdated and it also seems to have a PHP vulnerability. Your explanation is superb. Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: By the way, it shows bitcoin only, not bitcoind.
8333/tcp   open     bitcoin